Unable to install ploty-resampler==0.8.1
I am facing this typical error while installing ploty-resampler==0.8.1 from a downloaded whl file in a server with RHEL 8.9 OS.
I am firing the following command:
pip3 install -v plotly-resampler==0.8.1  --no-index --find-links=./mssuser_package

Inside the mssuser_package folder, I have downloaded from pypi site and kept the wheel file 
plotly_resampler-0.8.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_31_x86_64.whl
My python version is 3.8.10.
On installing it gives the following error:
Given no hashes to check 0 links for project 'plotly-resampler': discarding no candidates
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement plotly-resampler==0.8.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for plotly-resampler==0.8.1
Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 173, in _merge_into_criterion
    raise RequirementsConflicted(criterion)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.RequirementsConflicted: Requirements conflict: SpecifierRequirement('plotly-resampler==0.8.1')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/resolvelib/resolvers.py", line 343, in resolve
    raise ResolutionImpossible(e.criterion.information)
pip._vendor.resolvelib.resolvers.ResolutionImpossible: [RequirementInformation(requirement=SpecifierRequirement('plotly-resampler==0.8.1'), parent=None)]

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "/u01/mssuser/Python-3.8.10/Python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/resolution/resolvelib/resolver.py", line 136, in resolve
    raise error from e
pip._internal.exceptions.DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for plotly-resampler==0.8.1
Removed build tracker: '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-z987pb84'

I dont know where I am going wrong. Please help to resolve this issue.

Have you tried installing the wheel file directly? pip3 install <PATH to wheel>

Are you sure the whl file is valid (if it is, you should be able to open it as zip.)?

The issue is likely with 'manylinux_2_31' tag in the wheel file, which is not compatible with RHEL 8.9
to resolve this issue, here is few options

Downgrage the wheel file: look for wheel file with compatible tag, 'manylinux_2_24' or 'manylinux2014'. you can search for any older version.

Build the package from source: instead of pre-built wheel file, try this.
pip3 install -v plotly-resampler=0.8.1 --no-index --find-links=./mssuser_package --no-library :all:


this will force pip to rebuild the package from source.
If none this work, try to upgrade to python version 3.9 or later.

These kinds of pip errors mostly came with mismatched versions of required libraries or packages. When I come across these kinds of errors, what I do is check the version history of the package I require in PyPI, if it is available. Get the release date and look for other important packages used by this package. In this case, it uses numpy and pandas (given in the plotly-resampler project's GitHub) which are some of the main packages. And get the package's latest version of that date (in this case, its numpy==1.23.2 released on Aug 14, 2022), given that PyPI has that version. Most of the time, pip displays those version mismatches, but most probably since you installed it using whl it didn't.
